# AJAX to JS variable exchange

Tags: php, html, ajax

I used ajax to call a php to get me some values stored in my DB.
I then echo these values in my php so that i can use the `responseText` property to get these retrieved values (which i want to store in a JS array) for further referral.
Here's where i get stuck. I do manage to do this when I have to retrieve just 1 row from the DB (I did this by separating the fields using a ',' and subsequently using the split() function in JS to parse the string). However when my DB returns more than 1 row then I reach a deadend as this method of mine doesn't seem to work. Kindly advice the easiest way to overcome this hurdle.

Comment: I think your `.` key is stuck on your keyboard. Edited.

Comment: why not create a php array on the DB return and then json_encode it?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    var jsArray = {};
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
       jsArray[i] = item;
    });
```

the above JQuery loop is equivalent to PHP loop:

```
   foreach($response as $i => $item) {
      $jsArray[$i] = $item;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the PHP array of multiple DB rows to json using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on server side and parse JSON on the client side using [javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html) reading help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript). A more code oriented answer needs some code in question to work with.